# How do I add an onclick listener in plain Purescript?

Tags: purescript

I've just started learning Purescript.  I'd like to experiment with it in a simple web page.  I want to start by learning only *plain* Purescript and not use any frameworks, such as Halogen or Pux etc.

I believe I'll need to use the `purescript-web-html` package to register a button click event.  I searched for, but didn't find any beginner level examples of using this package to listen for and handle html element events.

```
<script>
   function log_click() {
      console.log("clicked");
   }

   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {  
                
      document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = log_click;
   });
</script>
<body>
  <button id="myButton" >click me</button>
</body>
```

Here's my plain Purescript attempt:

```
logClick :: Effect Unit
logClick = log "button clicked"

main :: Effect Unit
main = do

  w <- window
  doc <- document w
  buttonMaybe <- getElementById "myButton" $ toNonElementParentNode doc

  myEventTarget <- case buttonMaybe of
    Nothing -> throw "element with id 'myButton' not found."
    Just myButtonElem -> toEventTarget myButtonElem

  let listener =  eventListener logClick 

  addEventListener click listener true myEventTarget
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your attempt?

Comment: First compile error was `Could not match type Element with type Node` for line `Just myButtonElem -> toEventTarget myButtonElem`

Comment: Switching from import `Web.DOM.Node (toEventTarget)` to `Web.DOM.Element (toEventTarget)` fixed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt is almost there. The are a few small trivial problems.

**First**, `toEventTarget` is a pure function, not an effect. So you can't have it on the right side of `<-`.

But no fear: if you have a pure value, it's easy to wrap it in an effect by using `pure`:

```
  myEventTarget <- case buttonMaybe of
    Nothing -> throw "element with id 'myButton' not found."
    Just myButtonElem -> pure $ toEventTarget myButtonElem
```

**Second**, you have the opposite problem with `eventListener`: it's an effectful function, but you're binding it with `let` like a pure value. Just use the `<-` bind:

```
listener <- eventListener logClick
```

**Finally**, the type of parameter `eventListener` expects is a function `Event -> Effect Unit`, but your `logClick` is just an `Effect Unit`. Just give it an `Event` parameter. You don't have to actually use it:

```
logClick :: Event -> Effect Unit
logClick _ = log "button clicked"
```

**And with that**, here's the whole working piece:

```
logClick :: Event -> Effect Unit
logClick _ = log "button clicked"

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  w <- window
  doc <- document w
  buttonMaybe <- getElementById "myButton" $ toNonElementParentNode doc

  myEventTarget <- case buttonMaybe of
    Nothing -> throw "element with id 'myButton' not found."
    Just myButtonElem -> pure $ toEventTarget myButtonElem

  listener <- eventListener logClick

  addEventListener click listener true myEventTarget
```

**In conclusion**, while the above technically works, it can be written a bit shorter and more concisely by composing functions where convenient instead of giving their results names:

```
main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  window >>= document <#> toNonElementParentNode
  >>= getElementById "myButton"
  >>= traverse_ \button -> do
    listener <- eventListener \_ -> log "button clicked"
    addEventListener click listener true (toEventTarget button)
```

Comment: Revised my code with your fixes. It works!  I'd seen `pure` used in Purescript By Example, but didn't understand what it actually did.  You helped me see that it de-Effects things to give a desired type.

Comment: Thanks for showing the concise composable style.  It'll be a while before I can comprehend it.  In the mean time, my clunky verbose style lets me remember how each step works, even when I haven't looked at my code in a few weeks.

Comment: BTW, I see you've answered many Purescript questions.  It is very kind of you to help people who are using Purescript to increase their understanding of functional programming.  I appreciate your friendly, encouraging approach.

Comment: Glad to help :-)